# Entity Framework Error: An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In my application I have the following code...

```
    public Boolean SaveUserInformation(UserInfoDTO UserInformation)
    {
        return dataManager.SaveUserInfo(new UserInfo()
        {
            UserInfoID = UserInformation.UserInfoID.HasValue ? UserInformation.UserInfoID.Value : 0,
            UserID = UserInformation.UserID,
            ProxyUsername = UserInformation.ProxyUsername,
            Email = UserInformation.Email,
            Status = UserInformation.Status
        });
    }
```

This code calls a method on a dataManager object that utilizes Entity Framework...

```
    public Boolean SaveUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        try
        {
            //Validate data prior to database update
            if (userInfo.UserID == null) { throw new Exception("UserInfoDomainModel object passed to PriorityOne.Data.DataManager.SaveUserInfo with UserID property set to NULL."); }
            if (userInfo.ProxyUsername == null) { throw new Exception("UserInfoDomainModel object passed to PriorityOne.Data.DataManager.SaveUserInfo with ProxyUsername property set to NULL."); }
            if (userInfo.Email == null) { throw new Exception("UserInfoDomainModel object passed to PriorityOne.Data.DataManager.SaveUserInfo with Email property set to NULL."); }

            if (userInfo.UserInfoID == 0)
            {
                //Perform Insert
                using (PriorityOneEntities entities = new PriorityOneEntities())
                {
                    entities.UserInfoes.AddObject(userInfo);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Perform Update
                using (PriorityOneEntities entities = new PriorityOneEntities())
                {
                    entities.Attach(userInfo);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Log Error
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The insert on this code works just fine.  But when I try to perform an update I'm getting an error saying: "An object with a null EntityKey value cannot be attached to an object context."

It occurs on this line of code: entities.Attach(userInfo);

What I'm trying to accomplish is to avoid making a round trip to the database just to select the record that I will later make changes to and update, thus making two round trips to the database.

Any ideas what is going wrong, or how I could better accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<del>Seems like you're using EF 4.1+</del>  
You have to tell EF that you want your entity to be updated (Modified state):

```
//Perform Update
using (PriorityOneEntities entities = new PriorityOneEntities())
{
    entities.Entry(userInfo).State = EntityState.Modified;
    entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

P.S. You don't have to explicitly call `Attach`. It's done under the hood.

**Update**:
based on your comments, you're using EF 4.0. Here's what you have to do to attach your object as modified in EF 4.0:

```
 ctx.AddObject("userInfoes", userInfo);
 ctx.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(userInfo, EntityState.Modified);
 ctx.SaveChanges();
```

You cannot use `Attach` method. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx:

> If more than one entity of a particular type has the same key value, the Entity Framework will throw an exception. To avoid getting the exception, use the **AddObject** method to attach the detached objects and then change the state appropriately.

Comment: It was the first thing I'd thought of but the error would have been different. Right?

Comment: Theerror is because your entity is in "Added" state. But you have a similar entity in database with the same primary key. you have to manually change the state. Tested and works ok.

Comment: I don't seem to have access to the Entry() method on my entities object.  Can you give me a little more guidance?

Comment: What version of EF do you use? 4.1+ or 4.0?

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure how to check, but I am using .net 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx)

> The object that is passed to the Attach method must have a valid
> EntityKey value. If the object does not have a valid EntityKey value,
> use the AttachTo method to specify the name of the entity set.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I utilized that AttachTo method like this: entities.AttachTo(entities.UserInfoes.EntitySet.Name, userInfo); And that takes care of the error.  I'm no longer having an exception, but I am not seeing the changes in the database.

Comment: Try this [article](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/11/27/attaching-modified-entities-in-ef-4.aspx).

Comment: Have you tried the following: `dc.AttachToOrGet(userInfo.EntityKey.EntitySetName, ref userInfo);` ? This works fine for me (where `dc` is the data context). Especially, if the same object exists already somewhere else then it gets you the original reference pointing to the same instance.

Comment: There is no AttachToOrGet. Is this some extension that you made?